# How to retrieve vendor proposals

Tags: upwork-api

I'm trying to pull vendorProposals from UpWorks GraphQL API. I generated this query in the GraphQL API Explorer. Any help is appreciated.

query:

```
{
    vendorProposals(filter: {status_eq: Accepted}, sortAttribute: {field: CREATEDDATETIME, sortOrder: DESC}, pagination: {first: 100, after: "1"}) {
    totalCount
  }
}
```

error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Input parameter provided has incorrect value",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 2
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "vendorProposals"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "VJCA-6",
        "details": ""
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

I swapped out query parameters and regardless what I try, I get the same generic error.